# Vectorizing apply(list) and explode in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with dates in an integer format (timedelta in days from some arbitrary date) and using another column `weeks` I'd like to add 7 days to the `start_date` column for every `week > 1` and explode that into another row.

So records with 1 week would remain the same, 2 weeks would get get one additional row, 3 weeks would get 2 additional rows, etc - each additinal row would have `start_date` incremented by 7.

It's fairly trivial using `pd.apply` with `axis=1`, but I can't seem to wrap my head around a vectorized method to solve this.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'product':['a','b','c'], 'start_date':[1000,1000,1000], 'weeks':[1,2,3]})
```

Starting df

```
  product  start_date  weeks
0       a        1000      1
1       b        1000      2
2       c        1000      3
```

Current approach

```
df['dates'] = df.apply(lambda x: [x['start_date']+i*7 for i in range(x['weeks'])], axis=1)
df = df.explode('dates').drop(columns=['start_date']).rename({'dates':'start_date'})
```

Output

```
  product  weeks dates
0       a      1  1000
1       b      2  1000
1       b      2  1007
2       c      3  1000
2       c      3  1007
2       c      3  1014
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html#pandas-dataframe-loc) + [`index.repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) to scale up the DataFrame, then [`groupby cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) to add the multiple, then [`drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html#pandas-dataframe-drop) the column:

```
# Scale up DataFrame
df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['weeks'])]
# Create Dates Column grouping by the index (level=0)
df['dates'] = df['start_date'].add(df.groupby(level=0).cumcount().mul(7))
# Drop Column
df = df.drop('start_date', axis=1)
```

`df`:

```
  product  weeks  dates
0       a      1   1000
1       b      2   1000
1       b      2   1007
2       c      3   1000
2       c      3   1007
2       c      3   1014
```

---

Timing Information:

```
import pandas as pd

sample_df = pd.DataFrame({'product': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
                   'start_date': [1000, 1000, 1000],
                   'weeks': [1, 2, 3]})
```

[OP's Original Code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68155272/15497888)

```
def orig(df):
    df['dates'] = df.apply(
        lambda x: [x['start_date'] + i * 7 for i in range(x['weeks'])], axis=1)
    df = df.explode('dates').drop(columns=['start_date']).rename(
        {'dates': 'start_date'})

%timeit orig(sample_df)
3.53 ms ± 436 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

This answer:

```
def fn(df):
    df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['weeks'])]
    df['dates'] = df['start_date'].add(df.groupby(level=0).cumcount().mul(7))
    df = df.drop('start_date', axis=1)

%timeit fn(sample_df)
1.63 ms ± 43 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

[OP's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68155354/15497888)

```
def fn2(df):
    df['x'] = df['weeks'].apply(lambda x: range(x))
    df = df.explode('x')
    df['start_date'] = df['start_date'] + (df['x'] * 7)
    df.drop(columns='x', inplace=True)

%timeit fn2(sample_df)
2.71 ms ± 18.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, same concept just a slightly different order.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'product':['a','b','c'], 'start_date':[1000,1000,1000], 'weeks':[1,2,3]})
df['x'] = df['weeks'].apply(lambda x:range(x))
df = df.explode('x')
df['start_date'] = df['start_date']+(df['x']*7)
df.drop(columns='x', inplace=True)
```